# TimedPromise timed out when using webdriver.get() method while visiting multiple url's

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Setup:

- Selenium Version: 3.141.0
- Mozilla: 90.0.2 (64-bit)
- geckodriver: 0.29.1

I'm having trouble understanding why I am getting this error and would appreciate any help. I am going through a list of websites to visit through a headless browser (Firefox) using selenium Python. It runs ok in the beginning, but then randomly seems to come across a Timeout error at the `driver.get` method. Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/blujay95/projects/crawler/extract.py", line 333, in get_product_page_data
    self.browser.get_url(full_url)
  File "/Users/blujay95/projects/crawler/requestor.py", line 83, in get_url
    
  File "/Users/blujay95/.pyenv/versions/dora-3.8.7/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/blujay95/.pyenv/versions/dora-3.8.7/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/blujay95/.pyenv/versions/dora-3.8.7/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: TimedPromise timed out after 300000 ms
```

At this point, I have to quit the current driver object, start a new driver object, and then resume visiting the list of url's. After some time, it runs into the issue again.

Would love to get any help on how to approach diagnosing this issue.

Adding a code snippet that I call when looping through a list of websites to visit. The requestor object is a webdriver object.

```
class exampleObject:

    ...

    def start(self):
        if self.method == 'SELENIUM':
            options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
            options.headless = False
            options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36")
            self.requestor = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)


    def get_url(self, url):
        self.response = self.requestor.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet ? looks like you may need implicit wait

Comment: you can try sending the Escape key (use actions) when you receive this exception.  This should stop page loading.  (for infinitely loading pages...)  You should then be able to use another .get() on the current window.    If that fails you might try sending navigate.back(), or open a new tab and switch the driver's context to it and continue...

Comment: Added the code snippet. For the implicit wait, I had set implicitly_wait(100) and set_page_load_timeout(60) which ended up receiving the same timeout issue, but delayed by the wait value and load timeout value.

Comment: @pcalkins these are simple product pages in a shopping website so nothing too fancy. When I received this error, if I try to use a .get() method, I receive a marionette error (not sure how they are related). Thanks - I'll try those suggestions, but what's the diagnosis here?

Comment: occasionally you come across a site that infinitely loads.  Part of Selenium's check for whether a page has loaded is to read the readystate.  In the case where there's a constant polling happening, the ready state may not ever return what Selenium expects.  (or in the time slice where it is checking for that state... meaning it can go from "loading" to "ready" and then back to "loading" again, but Selenium has missed that "ready" state.)

Comment: You can also set PageLoadStrategy of the driver, (so it doesn't wait), but this will need a different strategy for the whole test and may cause some timing issues.

Comment: now that I think more on it, I don't think PageLoadStrategy would help if this is an infinitely loading page.  Selenium can't inject anything because the page will constantly be in a loading state...

Comment: Is it possible to surface the 'state' and catch it explicitly if it has been in 'loading' for a set number of seconds? Also, I've decided that webdriver.back() with a 3 second sleep is an acceptable workaround for the time being.

Comment: So I've been taking a closer look at the memory consumption while it is visiting and grabbing data from each site, and that seems to be causing this issue. What's strange that I don't understand is, if you have a list of different websites where we execute a webdriver.get() against it, why would memory accumulate instead of being released after each execution?